# Changing attributes of a pure html tag (= no "runat=server")

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In a page of my school project website there are a couple of divs I would like to be able to control from the code behind.

I know the easiest way to do that is to add `runat="server"` and simply do whatever, but unfortunately the IDs of those divs have a variable embedded in them, which makes it impossible for me to add the `runat` attribute to their tags (because it doesn't let me).

The only solution I can think of is to add those divs dynamically from the code behind and then be able to control them while still using that variable in their IDs.

What I wanted to ask is whether there is an easier way to do that, because the above solution would require quite some code editing which is kind of a pain at this point and I'd like to avoid it if possible. In addition, div written in html are much easier on the eye, which is definitely a big plus since it's a school project.

P.S: Yes I have searched before, but none of the answers applied to my question. I know about `Request.Form[]` but my page doesn't include a form so I'm not sure whether I can use it or not.

Comment: You can't - you need to come up with an alternative approach to managing the IDs. Why do they need to have a variable embedded in them? Unfortunately, clean, nicely-formatted HTML is not a product of WebForms.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to control about these divs. But full control really only comes from runat=server or maybe by using a datarepeater.

Comment: @Gavin - I only need to be able to change the css class of the div.

Comment: I fear you're out of luck. No `runat="server"` means no way to control directly from the code behind. Your best alternative as far as I can see it is client side scripting and/or AJAX. (e.g. output a client side mapping object holding the desired class for each div, then loop in client side script to assign it)

Comment: if you are only changing css then you could do something like <div id="myDiv1" class="<%=getClassForDiv(1) %>"> </div> where getClassForDiv returns the class for div for the element associated with, in this case 1